# x-axis labels move to top of graph after using

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph

I am using [Rotate Tick Label](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722) to change the labels on the x-axis to a vertical orientation.

Before using the rotate tick label function the labels on the x-axis are on the bottom of the graph:

[image]

After the following command:

```
TH= rotateTickLabel(gca,90);
```

the graph looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the labels to stay on the bottom of the graph and not move to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because on plots made with 'plot' the YTicks are defined from bottom up. And on image plots (made with 'image') the YTicks are defined from top down. Make the following two changes to rotateticklabel.m:

Edit line 54 so that it looks like this:

```
th=text(b,repmat(c(end)-.1*(c(end-1)-c(end)),length(b),1),a,'HorizontalAlignment','right','rotation',rot);
```

Edit line 56 to look like this:

```
th=text(b,repmat(c(end)-.1*(c(end-1)-c(end)),length(b),1),a,'HorizontalAlignment','left','rotation',rot);
```

For completion, the entire rotateticklabel.m should look like this:

```
function th=rotateticklabel(h,rot,demo)
%ROTATETICKLABEL rotates tick labels
%   TH=ROTATETICKLABEL(H,ROT) is the calling form where H is a handle to
%   the axis that contains the XTickLabels that are to be rotated. ROT is
%   an optional parameter that specifies the angle of rotation. The default
%   angle is 90. TH is a handle to the text objects created. For long
%   strings such as those produced by datetick, you may have to adjust the
%   position of the axes so the labels don't get cut off.
%
%   Of course, GCA can be substituted for H if desired.
%
%   TH=ROTATETICKLABEL([],[],'demo') shows a demo figure.
%
%   Known deficiencies: if tick labels are raised to a power, the power
%   will be lost after rotation.
%
%   See also datetick.

%   Written Oct 14, 2005 by Andy Bliss
%   Copyright 2005 by Andy Bliss

%DEMO:
if nargin==3
    x=[now-.7 now-.3 now];
    y=[20 35 15];
    figure
    plot(x,y,'.-')
    datetick('x',0,'keepticks')
    h=gca;
    set(h,'position',[0.13 0.35 0.775 0.55])
    rot=90;
end

%set the default rotation if user doesn't specify
if nargin==1
    rot=90;
end
%make sure the rotation is in the range 0:360 (brute force method)
while rot>360
    rot=rot-360;
end
while rot<0
    rot=rot+360;
end
%get current tick labels
a=get(h,'XTickLabel');
%erase current tick labels from figure
set(h,'XTickLabel',[]);
%get tick label positions
b=get(h,'XTick');
c=get(h,'YTick');
%make new tick labels
if rot<180
    th=text(b,repmat(c(end)-.1*(c(end-1)-c(end)),length(b),1),a,'HorizontalAlignment','right','rotation',rot);
else
    th=text(b,repmat(c(end)-.1*(c(end-1)-c(end)),length(b),1),a,'HorizontalAlignment','left','rotation',rot);
end
```

Once you edit rotateticklabel.m you can now successfully use it on plots made with 'image' as in this short example:

```
A = magic(5);
image(A)
datetick('x',0,'keepticks')
h=gca;
set(h,'position',[0.13 0.35 0.775 0.55])
rot=90;
th = rotateticklabel(h,30)
```